# Twitter4j - import issue - AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, twitter4j

I've migrated an Eclipse example to Androidstudio gradle type project.

I've added twitter4j libraries to module build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j:4.0.3'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.3'
    compile 'com.twitter:hbc-twitter4j-v3:1.4.2'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-http2-support:4.0.3'
}
```

It's importing twitter4j classes, but not these ones:

```
import twitter4j.http.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.http.RequestToken;
```

It says cannot resolve symbol `http`

I've tried importing the twitter4j.http but nothing I just can't make it work.

I'm using:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
}
```

Anybody can shed some light on this?

I've looked for hours but no solution yet :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AccessToken](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/auth/AccessToken.html) is in the `twitter4j.auth` package. I assume there is a similar problem with your other classes. It appears that the package structure has been rearranged from earlier versions. I suggest you bookmark the [twitter4j JavaDocs](http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/4.0.3/index.html) and refer to them regularly.

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I cannot find twitter4j.auth package on project's dependencies maven search... It is under another name, maybe?

Comment: @NeoVe This has nothing to do with maven and every thing to do with Java package structure. In your imports, simply change `twitter4j.http` to `twitter4j.auth`. Alternatively, you can delete the imports completely and use Eclipse's Organize Imports feature. I suggest that you learn about Java packages.

Comment: Yeah just changed that import, it's working now, thank you very much, I'll do it, I'm fairly new to java and android :)